# Javascript - htc behavior has no effect on newly created elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-components

I'm trying to identify objects in javascript. My problem is, that msie DOM nodes are not instances of any Object descendant, so I cannot set or get property on such an instance. I'm trying to make a workaround for that with htc behaviors (only nodes with style can have behavior, so this is a half solution, but better than nothing):

identity.htc:

```
<PUBLIC:COMPONENT>
<script type="text/javascript">
for(property in Object.prototype)
{
    element[property]=Object.prototype[property];
}
</script>
</PUBLIC:COMPONENT>
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript identity workaround</title>

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
*{behavior:url(identity.htc)}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">

(function ()
{
    var i=0;
    var table={};
    Object.prototype.identity=function ()
    {
        if (!this.__hashcode__)
        {
            this.__hashcode__=++i;
            table[i]=this;
        }
        return this.__hashcode__;
    };
    Object.identify=function (i)
    {
        return table[i];
    };
})();

window.onload=function ()
{
    var body=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var existingElement=document.getElementById("existingElement");
    var newElement=document.createElement("div");
        newElement.addBehavior("identity.htc");
    alert(body.identity()); //1
    alert(existingElement.identity()); //2
    alert(newElement.identity()); // expected: 3, real: method not supported
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="existingElement"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, that I cannot use the identity method on the newly created elements. I tried to add the behavior with the addBehavior method, but it didn't help. Has somebody a solution for this?

Comment: Extending `Object.prototype` breaks `for in` loops. You then need to add hasOwnProperty to all your loops. And you do realize that behaviors are an IE only feature that really hogs your CPU?

Comment: Do you know another solution in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
<PUBLIC:COMPONENT lightWeight="true">
```